# GET method has taken by Django

Tags: python, django, methods, get, django-errors

I am a beginner in Django and I am creating Django forms for getting input and processing. I created my app called 'artists' and I have coded the files as follows.
My error is [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVqgp.png)
This is my urls.py in server folder

```
"""mysite URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^artists/', include('artists.urls')),
]
```

These are my files in 'artists' app
-> urls.py <-

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^artists/', views.artistcreate, name="artistcreate")]
```

-> views.py <-

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from datetime import datetime
from artists.models import *

def artistcreate(request):
    if request.method=="GET":
        form=ArtistForm()
        return render(request,'artists/create.html',{'form':form})
    elif request.method=="POST":
        form=ArtistForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/artists')
```

-> models.py <-

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Artist(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    year_formed=models.PositiveIntegerField()

class ArtistForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Artist
        fields=['name','year_formed']
```

-> artists/create.html <- this html file is in my templates folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form }}
<button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I need help to create a django form which receives input and that can be able to process.Thanks in advance

Comment: "If you submit me any codes that can be fulfill my requirements will be useful". That's not the way Stack Overflow works. Please take the [tour], read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic], and read [ask].

Comment: It looks like you've got a form, a controller, and a template. Exactly what part of this isn't working?

Comment: you are missing the action attribute of your `form` tag. try adding `action="{% url 'artist:artistcreate' %}"` to your `form` tag

Comment: What error are you getting??? You may need to call `form.is_valid()` before saving it in your view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `form.is_valid()` before saving the form. When the `is_valid()` method is called, the validations on the form are run and a boolean is returned whether `form` is valid or not.

You may need some changes in your view,

```
def artistcreate(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = ArtistForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/artists')
    else:
        form = ArtistForm()
    return render(request,'artists/create.html',{'form':form})
```